# Pointers c++ "w does not name a type"

Tags: c++, pointers

When im trying to compile code below im getting an error

> wskazniki.cpp:7:1: error: 'w' does not name a type  w = &liczba;
> //wybieramy zeby wskazywal na zmienna liczba

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int liczba=144;//wskaznik to zmienna ktora przechowuje adres innej zmiennej
int *w; //tworzymy wskaznik typu int
w = &liczba; //wybieramy zeby wskazywal na zmienna liczba

int main()
{
    cout<<w;
    cout<<*w;

    return 0;
}
```

I was trying to follow tutorial from 2014 year so it could be a reason why this doesnt work anymore.

Comment: `w = &liczba;` can't be at that scope. It isn't a declaration or a definition

Comment: `w = &liczba;` cannot be at global scope, either initialize `int* w = &liczba;` or move assignation in `main`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot place statements like

```
w = &liczba; //wybieramy zeby wskazywal na zmienna liczba
```

outside function body.

You should put that inside function body

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int liczba=144;//wskaznik to zmienna ktora przechowuje adres innej zmiennej
int *w; //tworzymy wskaznik typu int

int main()
{
    w = &liczba; //wybieramy zeby wskazywal na zmienna liczba
    cout<<w;
    cout<<*w;

    return 0;
}
```

Or merge it as the initialization of variable

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int liczba=144;//wskaznik to zmienna ktora przechowuje adres innej zmiennej
int *w = &liczba; //tworzymy wskaznik typu int

int main()
{
    cout<<w;
    cout<<*w;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh thank you so much, im beginner in c++ so sorry for asking so stupid questions :)

Comment: and yes there was question before like mine but asked in different way so i wasnt able to find it i was thinking thats because of pointers not because of variable scope